# Bootstrap 3 Sticky Footer (Wordpress Theme) Responsive

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming

Im working on a wordpress 4 bootstrap theme and Im trying to figure out the footer alignment for the social icons (font awesome) in my custom wordpress theme footer.php file.

In bootstrap  test page the footer works with padding above and below the rows with the social icons.

Its using this class: "footer class="section section-primary"

Here is the full page working in bootstrap:

```html
<html>
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="cover">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-ex-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span>Brand</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Contacts</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cover-image" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1418065460487-3e41a6c84dc5?q=25&amp;fm=jpg&amp;s=127f3a3ccf4356b7f79594e05f6c840e);"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1 class="text-inverse">Heading</h1>
            <p class="text-inverse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici eli.</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Click me</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/assets/placeholder.png"
            class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 class="text-primary">A title</h1>
            <h3>A subtitle</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
              ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
              dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies
              nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
              Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In
              enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum
              felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
              elementum semper nisi.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 class="text-primary">A title</h1>
            <h3>A subtitle</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
              ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
              dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies
              nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
              Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In
              enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum
              felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
              elementum semper nisi.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/assets/placeholder.png"
            class="img-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center text-primary">Team</h1>
            <p class="text-center">We are a group of skilled individuals.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/assets/user_placeholder.png"
            class="center-block img-circle img-responsive">
            <h3 class="text-center">John Doe</h3>
            <p class="text-center">Developer</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/assets/user_placeholder.png"
            class="center-block img-circle img-responsive">
            <h3 class="text-center">John Doe</h3>
            <p class="text-center">Developer</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/assets/user_placeholder.png"
            class="center-block img-circle img-responsive">
            <h3 class="text-center">John Doe</h3>
            <p class="text-center">Developer</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="section section-primary">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Footer header</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,
              <br>sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
              <br>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="text-info text-right">
              <br>
              <br>
            </p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm text-left">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-instagram text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-twitter text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-facebook text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-github text-inverse"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs text-right">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-instagram text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-twitter text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-facebook text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-github text-inverse"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

In my wordpress theme (footer.php) I had issues with the footer not sticking to the bottom of the page when using the bootstrap footer class ("footer class="section section-primary") it did align properly like in the above bootstrap code.

To get the sticky footer to work in my wordpress theme, I had to use the class "footer" and I did the following with css & js to get my footer to stick to the bottom:

```js
var bumpIt = function() {
      $('body').css('margin-bottom', $('.footer').height());
    },
    didResize = false;

bumpIt();

$(window).resize(function() {
  didResize = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if(didResize) {
    didResize = false;
    bumpIt();
  }
}, 100);
```

```css
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 140px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  /*height: 140px; */
  background-color: #313131;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


       <!-- ========== FOOTER ========== -->
   <footer class="footer">
   <div class="section section-primary">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>My Website</h1>
            <p>&copy; <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php echo date('Y'); ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="text-info text-right">
              <br>
              <br>
            </p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm text-left">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-instagram text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-twitter text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-facebook text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-github text-inverse"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs text-right">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-instagram text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-twitter text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-facebook text-inverse"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-fw fa-github text-inverse"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>




</body>
</html>
```

In footer.php The font awesome rows are right on the bottom. Id like them to have some padding below them like in the first bootstrap only example.

I tried changing the wordpress theme footer.php  footer class from "footer" to "section section-primary" and that works but breaks my sticky footer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: With 'sticky footer' you mean it stays on the page, right? or is this me misunderstanding?

Comment: I mean by sticky footer, the footer always stay at the very bottom of the page with no space under it or it sticks always to the bottom. Thanks

Comment: without the .js and css on some theme pages the footer has space below it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the `<footer></footer>` in the `<body></body>` and calling `margin:0;` on your body at the very top of your CSS file.

This removes all margin at first, but is overwritten when you add a margin to let's say your footer or any other element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Im not sure Im explaining it. Im working on footer.php in my wordpress theme.  In bootstrap only the footer on xs screens the footer and social icons look like  http://winterfall.eu/1.png

In my wordpress theme - footer.php with my css & js to make the footer stay on the bottom of the page, the social icons are flush on the bottom  http://winterfall.eu/2.png  &  http://winterfall.eu/3.png

Comment: wordpress footer.php is using the class "footer" which works with my js & css.  In bootstrap only the footer class "section section-primary" works like Im trying to duplicate in the wordpress theme.